# Is there a way to set cpu affinity for a thread in linux to "follow" main thread?`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to instruct linux to spawn a worker thread, but multiplex it on the same CPU as the parent, without pinning both to a particular CPU?

Answer (score 0):

To multiplex all threads on the same socket, you want [compact scheduling](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html), which can be achieved in a couple of ways.

If you already have the workers, use [`taskset`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) or [`numactl`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl) to get the current parent affinity, then move the child to the same socket. The obvious disadvantage here is that it's post-hoc.

If you haven't set fired up the master, set the [`KMP_AFFINITY=compact`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522691) environment variable for Intel OpenMP environments, or [`OMP_PROC_BIND=master`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fPROC_005fBIND.html#OMP_005fPROC_005fBIND) for GNU OpenMP environments. This is pre-hoc, but requires you know your compilation environment, or at least cover all the cases.

Comment: I probably should have said "core" instead of "CPU", I'd like to get the two threads multiplexed on a single core, so they're time interleaved.

Comment: If you know the number of threads ahead of time, you can use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and `OMP_PROC_BIND=close` to [simulate it](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html#2-2-round-robin-scheduling), but otherwise I think you have to know the topology... at the end of the day, everything calls [`sched_setaffinity`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) which requires knowledge of the topology.